# Notation check, argmax of values in a set

Tags: notation

Among `C` different possible values for each `y` and `m` total `y`'s, I want to show the value with maximum number of $y$ having that value.

Let's assume there are $m$ different functions $y_1$,...,$y_m$ each of which can output a value from the set of possible outcomes `{1,...,C}`. I want to know what outcome is the most common among all the function outputs.

This is the notation that I have so far:

> $\hat{y}_i = \underset{c\in\{1,...,C\}}{\mathrm{argmax}}(\{y^{(j)}=c\}_{j=1}^m)$

Is this a correct notation?

Comment: ```counter``` is a dictionary but you use it like an array. Moreover, ```counter[i]``` is constant over all ```i``` (i.e. ```counter[i]=y[0]+...+y[m-1]``` which does not depend on ```i```). I think your code doesn't make much sense. This is also pretty off-topic, I would say. Maybe try stackoverflow?

Comment: I want to check the notation. Put the pseudocode just to clarify what I want by the notation. Counter is the indeed the dictionary counting the number of y's having a specific value

Comment: What about my other question, that ```counter[i]``` is constant independent of ```i```?

Comment: No, counter is a dictionary, keys are the possible outcomes, values are the number of y's having that specific outcome. Suppose outcomes are {0,1,2} and y's can be either one of them. I want to see which of 0, 1, 2 are the most common among y's.

Comment: May be I'll just remove the code since its distracting and try to explain with words! It seems that the code is not helping.

Comment: I think your code is just incorrect. Perhaps study what I've said carefully.

Comment: I think now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is
$$
c^{\star}\in\operatorname{argmax}_{c\in\{1,\ldots,C\}}(|\{i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}\colon y_{i}=c\}|).
$$
There were two issues in your formulation:

1. $\operatorname{argmax}$ returns a set (what if more than
   one element maximizes?), so you should use $\in$ instead of $=$.
2. $\operatorname{argmax}$ acts on collections that have a maximum (in your version, you were passing it a set with no clear ordering, let alone a maximum) so we need to take the cardinality $|\cdot|$.

Another issue, that also appeared in your code is that on the left-hand side, you have $i$. Why? Also, why call it $\hat{y}_i$ instead of something like $c^\star$ or $c_{\text{most}}$?

---

The above is a bit verbose, so perhaps

> $$ c^{\star}\in\operatorname{argmax}_{c}(|\{i\colon y_{i}=c\}|) $$

is best, since the intended meaning is clear.