# Argmax as a list

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a dataset X containing a column which I already computed using f(X). Now, I would like to get the maximum 30% of dataset X depending on the f(X) using argmax. Any help please?

Regards,
Soft.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you asking for the 70th percentile (point that marks top 30% of observations)?

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. I am trying to write an equation for my project using argmax like the one in the link (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871075/notation-check-argmax-of-values-in-a-set?rq=1). In other words, I have a dataset and would like to apply a specific function f on this dataset end extract the top 30% rows according to f. Is it possible to find a representation for this task using argmax function?